# Loading multiple variables using Highcharts and jquery with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts, multiple-columns

Hey people this is my first post but I'm an avid user of Stack overflow for previous solutions, I wouldn't have posted it if I could find the answer.

I'm using the following that uses the high charts events->load function to update the 12 data points as it's needed, which in my case is once every minute. I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong in this code.

graphpage.html:

```
<script src='scripts/jquery-latest.js'></script>
<script src='scripts/highcharts.js'></script>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="graph-unit">
  <dtitle>Other Information</dtitle>
  <hr>
  <div class="section-graph">
    <div id="active_power_container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="scripts/getgraphdata.php"></script>
```

getgraphdata.php:

```
<?
require_once 'datastuff.php';
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
?>
var collector_id='<?=$db->currentUser?>';
var meter_id=3;
var samples=60;
var mod=2;
var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'active_power_container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            events: {
            load: function() {
                var date,
                series1 = this.series[0],
                series2 = this.series[1],
                series3 = this.series[2],
                series4 = this.series[3],
                series5 = this.series[4],
                series6 = this.series[5],
                series7 = this.series[6],
                series8 = this.series[7],
                series9 = this.series[8],
                series10 = this.series[9],
                series11 = this.series[10],
                series12 = this.series[11],
                $sQry = '/i/data/graph_widget_data.php?collector_id='+collector_id+'&limit=1';
                setInterval(function() {

                    $.get($sQry , null, function(tsv) {
                        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                        $.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                            line = line.split(/\t/);
                            var date = line[0];
                            series1.addPoint([date, line[1]], true, true);
                            series2.addPoint([date, line[2]], true, true);
                            series3.addPoint([date, line[3]], true, true);
                            series4.addPoint([date, line[4]], true, true);
                            series5.addPoint([date, line[5]], true, true);
                            series6.addPoint([date, line[6]], true, true);
                            series7.addPoint([date, line[7]], true, true);
                            series8.addPoint([date, line[8]], true, true);
                            series9.addPoint([date, line[9]], true, true);
                            series10.addPoint([date, line[10]], true, true);
                            series11.addPoint([date, line[11]], true, true);
                            series12.addPoint([date, line[12]], true, true);
                        });

                    });




                }, 1000);
            }
        }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Active Power chart (meter: '+meter_id+')',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    hour: '%I %p',
                    minute: '%I:%M %p'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Active Power (Watts) '
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [<? $query = $db->DB("SELECT long_description,short_description FROM `desc_tbl` WHERE `id` = '{$db->getdata(3)}'");
    $num_rows = $query->num_rows;
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $title = $row['short_description'];
        if($title == ""){ $title = $row['long_description']; }
?>{
    name: '<?=$title?>'
}<? if($i < $num_rows){echo ","; $i++; }  }?>]
        }

        sQry= '/i/data/graph_widget_data.php?collector_id='+collector_id+'&meter_id='+parseInt(meter_id)+'&samples='+parseInt(samples)+'&mod='+parseInt(mod);


        jQuery.get(sQry , null, function(tsv) {
            var lines = [];
            traffic  = [];
            traffic1 = [];
            traffic2 = [];
            traffic3 = [];
            traffic4 = [];
            traffic5 = [];
            traffic6 = [];
            traffic7 = [];
            traffic8 = [];
            traffic9 = [];
            traffic10 = [];
            traffic11 = [];
            try {
                // split the data return into lines and parse them
                tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                    line = line.split(/\t/);
                    //date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                    date = line[0];
                    traffic.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic1.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[2].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic2.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[3].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic3.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[4].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);         
                    traffic4.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[5].replace(',', ''))
                    ]); 
                    traffic5.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[6].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic6.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[7].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic7.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[8].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic8.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[9].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic9.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[10].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);
                    traffic10.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[11].replace(',', ''))
                    ]);     
                    traffic11.push([
                        parseInt(date),
                        parseFloat(line[12].replace(',', ''))
                    ]); 
                });
            } catch (e) {  }
            options.series[0].data = traffic;
            options.series[1].data = traffic1;
            options.series[2].data = traffic2;
            options.series[3].data = traffic3;
            options.series[4].data = traffic4;
            options.series[5].data = traffic5;
            options.series[6].data = traffic6;
            options.series[7].data = traffic7;
            options.series[8].data = traffic8;
            options.series[9].data = traffic9;
            options.series[10].data = traffic10;
            options.series[11].data = traffic11;

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

The sQry outputs a line like:

> 1401896202400 0   0   0   0   0   97  0   0   0   0   0   0

Which is fine as it's getting the latest query but it doesn't do anything with it.
When I remove the events->load stuff it works fine, I can't seem to pinpoint my mistake. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adive you to use loop instead of 12 lines and call addPoint. Secondly in the addPoint you should use single redraw. In other words all series should have

```
series1.addPoint([date, line[12]], false, true);
```

but last

```
series12.addPoint([date, line[12]], true, true);
```

Then you will avoic multiple redrawing chart.

Referring to you data, perhaps, the problem is with the values which you use which are strings, instead of float. Try to use something like:

```
series1.addPoint([parseFloat(date), parseFloat(line[12])], false, true);
```

In general in your php I recommend you to return json (json_encode) and in the javascirpt use $.getJSON(), then you will avoid any problems with types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It has worked :) I have also taken the $.getJSON() into account and works perfectly :)